# is there a way to style the arrow of a select element?

Tags: html, css, styles

I am try to style the `<select> ... </select>` element using css. At the moment I am  able to change the color, border, width, height ... - but I have no idea how I can change the arrow (on the right), I want to use my own design, is there a way to accomplish it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look [here](http://bavotasan.com/2011/style-select-box-using-only-css/).

Basically you need to do something like this:

```
background: url(new_arrow.png) no-repeat right #ddd;
```

Comment: Wow, Ive never seen that hack before!

Answer (score 0):

You can not change it (across all major browsers)

You can use JavaScript though for much better styling.

See this jQuery plugin: http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/

There are also many other if jQuery is not you flavor.